# Frequent Timeout Exception in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, timeoutexception

I'm using the maven jetty plugin, version 9.1.2.v20140210.  Three times since I started the server 24 hours ago I've gotten this exception in the logs :

```
2014-03-04 16:34:01.878:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1119397307-111: Commit failed java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 2014-03-04 16:34:01.879:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1119397307-114: /favicon.ico java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingCallback.block(BlockingCallback.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.sendContent(HttpOutput.java:530)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:896)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:499)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:717)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1644)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1615)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:568)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1112)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1046)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:505)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Idle timeout expired: 30001/30000 ms
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout.checkIdleTimeout(IdleTimeout.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.IdleTimeout$1.run(IdleTimeout.java:50)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It has been for three different files each time.  The relevant entry in the request logs appears to be

```
[04/Mar/2014:21:33:31 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 93062
```

As far as I can tell, it has no adverse effect on the site yet.

I don't even know where to start to diagnose this problem - any help is appreciated.  Happy to post anything necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the client was working so slow that it couldn't create the HTTP connection properly, so after a while, your server throws a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException for that particular request.

Is that possible in your scenario?

Comment: I'm not sure; though, the website is open to world so I imagine any sort of client issue could happen.  Is there a way for me to check?

Comment: logging is probably the easy way :D @pail

Comment: Ha, fair enough. You've overestimated my competence, though - what should I be logging to determine if the client is at fault? I've got the request logs, but I'm not sure  if I should be able to tell from that or not.